# Is this operator unitary?

Tags: group-theory, unitary-matrices

It is well know that the operator $\exp\left[-i\Delta t\hat{H}\right]$ is a unitary operator if $\hat{H}$ is an Hermitian operator. The proof is based on Taylor expanding and affecting the dagger:
$\left(\exp\left[-i\Delta t\hat{H}\right]\right)^{\dagger}=\left(\boldsymbol{\hat{1}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-i\Delta t\hat{H})^{n}}{n!}\right)^{\dagger}=\boldsymbol{\hat{1}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(i\Delta t\hat{H})^{n}}{n!}=\left(\exp\left[i\Delta t\hat{H}\right]\right)^{-1}$.

However, in practical common problems of quantum physics, $\hat{H}$ denotes an operator which might become unbounded at some point. The most familiar one is the delta potential:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_potential

where $\hat{H}=\delta(x)$. Clearly, for that choice there is no justification for Taylor expanding and I'm also unsure how to the conjugation is supposed to act on $\infty$.

Is it really true that the operator $\exp\left[-i\Delta t\hat{H}\right]$ is still unitary for the choice of $\hat{H}=\delta(x)$ ? I cannot even see how to even define such an object, but surprisingly, the current approach assumes that the answer is positive.

Comment: Look for "Stone's theorem on one parameter unitary groups".

Comment: @ChadK: I did, but I can't get how this theorem claims to work for possibly unbounded operators. Can you please provide me with a proof for the particular case that I asked? I would be very much grateful as I failed to see how the Taylor expansion can be avoided.

Comment: What I would like to claim is that this cannot truly be done, and only $\sqrt{\left(\exp\left[-i\Delta t\delta(x)\right]\right)^{\dagger-1}\left(\exp\left[-i\Delta t\delta(x)\right]\right)^{-1}}\exp\left[-i\Delta t\delta(x)\right]$ should be regraded as unitary. any comments on that?

Comment: Stone's theorem does apply to unbounded infinitesimal generators, but multiplying by a delta-function potential is not even an unbounded operator.  It's just something physicists solve for unrigorously by working in the smooth regions around the delta spikes and patching together with boundary conditions where the singularities are.

Comment: @ChadK: Isn't such a choice of Hamiltonian satisfy the condition for unbounded operator? Do you agree that the operator that I wrote above is still unitary?

Comment: You can multiply $\delta$ by a continuous function $f$ to get $f(0)\delta$, but $f(0)\delta$ is not a member of any Hilbert space.  Even if you start with $f$ in some Hilbert space (e.g. square integrable continuous $f$), you end up outside of it.

Comment: I completely agree about that, but I am not sure what is your actual answer for my two questions above. My perspective is that $\exp\left[-i\Delta t\delta(x)\right]$ should be regarded as a non-unitary unbounded operator, since the standard argument above fails.

Comment: There is no definition of $\exp\left[-i\Delta t\delta(x)\right]$, because multiplication by $\delta$ is not any kind of operator on Hilbert space, bounded or not.  Physicists don't care about this.  They solve the time-invariant Schrödinger equation with potentials containing singularities, trying to find energy eigenvalues $E_n$ and energy eigenfunctions $\Psi_n(x)$, using boundary conditions at the singularities and at infinity.  If they find an energy eigenfunction $\Psi_n(x)$, the time-evolution is $\Psi_n(x)\exp(-iE_n t/\hbar)$ and they're exempt from having to explain this operator.

Comment: @ChadK: If I understood you correctly this relies on using the identity $\left|x\right\rangle \left\langle x\right|=\mathbf{\hat{1}}$. So that $\hat{U}(t,\,t_{0})\left|\Psi\right\rangle =\left|x\right\rangle \left\langle x\right|\hat{U}(t,\,t_{0})\left|\Psi\right\rangle =\left|x\right\rangle e^{-i\Delta t\,E_{n}}\Psi_{n}(x)$. Where in the last step we are acting with $\hat{U}(t,\,t_{0})$ on $\left|x\right\rangle$ instead of on $\left|\Psi\right\rangle$. However, it is not clear to me that this step is justified, since it involves taking the conjugation of a badly defined object.